# How to save a copy of this web page?

Tags: windows, browser, download, website, wget

I'd like to save a copy of this page offline so that I can grep through it:
http://forum.devmaster.net/t/advanced-rasterization/6145

But I'm unable to download a copy of this page with wget, saving from chrome only saves the first "page"; trying to print does the same, and disabling javascript displays garbage on the page.

Everything seems to be dynamically loaded as the page scrolls but this content cannot be "saved" offline.

Is there a way to download the contents of this page without having to copy/paste manually?

Comment: If you go all the way to the bottom first by clicking the double arrows next to the topic number and count and clicking Bottom, then printing it to a PDF from FireFox or Chrome (at least, those are the only two I tried) works on Mac OS X (and I'd guess on Windows as well although I don't have a Windows box to try it on) as does Firefox' ScrapBook extension. That's not very convenient if you want to do this on a bunch of pages, but for just one it's fine.

Comment: I tried doing this on Chome (Windows) and it ended up having blank pages.. ?

Comment: Ok, don't know then, sorry. I added the windows tag to the question to make it clear you're on Windows, and from our exchange, that obviously makes a difference.